# How to override external yaml applied to K8S?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to set up kubemq in my cluster, and this is the command the shown in their README

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://deploy.kubemq.io/community
```

There are a lot of empty field in that yaml and I want to customize it. How can I override an external yaml file applied by `kubectl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Kubernetes world, It's generally an unsafe idea to run a command like the below unless you trust the URL:

```
kubectl apply -f <some/web/url>
```

This is essentially the same as the following in the non-Kubernetes world:

```
curl </some/web/url> |bash
```

In both cases, we aren't inspecting the content downloaded from the URL and directly executing them by feeding to `kubectl` and `bash` directly. **What if the URL is compromised with some harmful code?**

A better approach is to break the single step into parts:

1. Download the manifest file
2. Inspect the manifest file.
3. Run kubectl apply/create on it, only you are satisfied.

**Example**:
*//download the file*

```
curl -fsSL -o downloaded.yml https://deploy.kubemq.io/community
```

*// inspect the file or edit the file*

*//Now apply the downloaded file after inspecting.*

```
kubectl apply -f downloaded.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just copy the content in a text file?
Change whatever you want and apply it.